# Is it safe to use boost serialization to serialize objects in C++ to a binary format for use over a socket?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, networking, tcp

I know that you can use boost serialization to serialize to a text format and then push over a socket, but I'd like to serialize a class of statistics data into a binary format (both for size and encoding/decoding overhead reasons).  Is it safe to use boost serialization for this?

My specific worries are:

1. Differences between integer type sizes on different platforms (mainly 32-bit vs 64-bit).
   Though I can largely get around this by using exactly-sized integer from stdint, I'd still like to understand the behavior.
2. Differences in endianness between systems, does boost serialize into a standard endian-ness (eg: network ordering), and then deserialize using the host's endianness?

It's a very nice library, but unfortunately documentation on it's binary capabilities is somewhat limited, so I just want to make sure that using it this way would be safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, in general boost ***binary*** serialization is not machine-independent. See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html).

Comment: The only thing I see relating to portability is this statement of one of their goals:

"Data Portability - Streams of bytes created on one platform should be readable on any other."

Comment: Ah. Silly frames. Check the updated link. Scroll down about 1/3.

Comment: Fraid I'm still not seeing it, can you quote a string I can ctrl-f on?

Comment: He might be referring to the first code block in the "Archive Models" section, where a comment describes the binary archive type as being non-portable.

Comment: Aha! subtle, I'll assume it's not safe to use it then.  Fortunately my classes are relatively simple, I'll just roll the serialization by hand.

Comment: In general it is portable, specific to binary archives it is not. This answer is quite a misrepresentation.

Comment: I wrote that boost *binary* serialization is not machine-independent. Please reread my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's available, I've been hearing a lot about Google's protobuf.  It has a C and [C++ binding](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/index.html).

Comment: I've never used protobuf and wasn't sure whether it would handle endianness correctly.  I did some searching and found this, which states that it will always deserialize to the local machine's native byte order, so it should work for your purposes:  http://markmail.org/message/3ewnsvs4dwvwt647?q=thread:3ewnsvs4dwvwt647#query:thread%3A3ewnsvs4dwvwt647+page:1+mid:lv5yjf7qefizc2bv+state:results

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Apache Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/).  It was designed by Facebook for cross platform serialization/deserialization.