# Serialization doubts

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, protocols

I have to create an application layer protocol for a C++ application, but I have some doubts about how I can do it, especially about the serialization:

1. My idea is to create a class for describing the header, something like this:

```cpp
class Header {
 int type;
 int length;
 char[] message;
}
```

Now, in order to serialize it and to pass it through a socket, I'm thinking about using Boost Serialization. But my question is: is it "cross-platform"? In the sense that if I want to receive the data into a Python/Ruby/any-other-language server with its own class, can I do it or not (since I've serialized a C++ class)?
If not, is useful to serialize the class data into a JSON/XML file and transmit it?

2. If I want to serialize an object into a string, Does I have to pay attention to the big/little-endian and/or the string encoding and/or other details?
3. Since, not all the machines using the same number of bytes to define, for example, the primitive data types, is it necessary to use something like uint32_t data types to force the system to use a certain amount of bytes?

Thank you very much!

Comment: please one question per question

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304061/is-it-safe-to-use-boost-serialization-to-serialize-objects-in-c-to-a-binary-fo) answer first.
2. Serializing into a C-style string is fine as far as big/little endian woes go, but is not as good performance-wise.
3. Using C-style string serialization will mostly solve this problem as well. On read side you should make sure that when parsing numbers they don't exceed local data size.

If this is a serious project then maybe consider using JSON or XML.